# How can needn't install Adobe Acrobat software but could regist Acrobat.dll

Tags: c#, .net

```
Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc pdfDoc = (Acrobat.CAcroPDDoc)Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.CreateObject("AcroExch.PDDoc", "");
```

In .net I want to use `acrobat.dll` but don't want to install the whole Adobe Acrobat software.

Comment: did you trying to read PDF file?

Comment: this question can be something like "want to use VB, but don't want to intall VB".
just install it, it's an external system, you don't try to outsmart their stuffs, unless you create you own.

Answer (score 0):

Is acrobat.dll a COM or COM+ and you have to register to GAC? if not, just screw it!!! I guess you want to deploy your application to server but you don't want to install Adobe Acrobat reader on server, right? If it is right, just embed dll into your package and deploy to server.